# PL/SQL split a string by " + " and sum the numbers in it?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sumNumbers(p VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS

...

SELECT sumNumbers('3 + 6 + 13 + 0 + 1') FROM dual;
```

So the output should be: `23`

Comment: Do you necessarily want to split it up, or do you really just want to evaluate the sum any way you can? Will it always only have plus signs, or could it have other operators, parentheses, etc.? Will the numbers always be positive integers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a 'trick' with XML and XPath evaluation to do this without manually tokenising the string:

```
select * from xmltable('3 + 6 + 13 + 0 + 1' columns result number path '.');

    RESULT
----------
        23
```

Or:

```
select to_number(xmlquery('3 + 6 + 13 + 0 + 1' returning content).getStringVal()) as result
from dual;

    RESULT
----------
        23
```

This is more flexible as other operators can be used:

```
select * from xmltable('2 * (5 + 7) - 3' columns result number path '.');

    RESULT
----------
        21
```

It doesn't like division using the normal `/` operator though, and you need to use `div` instead, so you might need to do a replace on your source string if it might contain a slash:

```
select * from xmltable('2 * (5 + 7) div 3' columns result number path '.');

    RESULT
----------
         8
```

Read more about [Oracle's XPath handling](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5123), and [XPath numeric operators](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/XPath_and_XPointer/XPath_Functions_and_Numeric_Operators#XPath_Numeric_Operators).

You can probably call that directly, without a function; but if you particularly wanted to wrap it in a function it's a little more complicated as the XPath has to be fixed at parse time, so you would need to use dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sumNumbers(p VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
  l_result NUMBER;
BEGIN
  execute immediate q'[select * from xmltable(']'
    || replace(p, '/', ' div ')
    || q'[' columns result number path '.')]'
  into l_result;

  return l_result;
END;
/

SELECT sumNumbers('3 + 6 + 13 + 0 + 1') FROM dual;

               SUMNUMBERS('3+6+13+0+1')
---------------------------------------
                                     23
```

I've used [the alternative quoting mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) to avoid escaping the single quotes in the statement, though I'm not sure it's much clearer here. And I've included the `replace()` in case you need to be able to divide, but it you don't want that then just concatenate `p` straight into the SQL statement. With the replace you can do:

```
SELECT sumNumbers('2 * (5 + 7) / 3') FROM dual;
```

If you are going to allow it to be flexible the function should have a different name...

Comment: Nice, never thought of (mis-) using XPath that way.

Comment: Thanks, but how should I implement your code into my function?

Comment: @andrasb - added a function that uses the XMLTable method.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the numbers with a hierarchical query and a regular expression and sum the results. Something like this:

```
WITH t AS (
   SELECT '3 + 6 + 13 + 0 + 1' numbers  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT SUM(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(numbers,'( ?[[:digit:]]+ ?)',1,LEVEL)))
FROM t
CONNECT BY LENGTH(SUBSTR(numbers,DECODE(REGEXP_INSTR(numbers,'( ?[[:digit:]]+ ?)',1,LEVEL),0,NULL,REGEXP_INSTR(numbers,'( ?[[:digit:]]+ ?)',1,LEVEL)))) <= LENGTH(SUBSTR(numbers,DECODE(REGEXP_INSTR(numbers,'( ?[[:digit:]]+ ?)',1,LEVEL),0,NULL,REGEXP_INSTR(numbers,'( ?[[:digit:]]+ ?)',1,LEVEL))));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to evaluate the expression, why don't you just - well - evaluate it?

```
 FUNCTION sumNumbers(p VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
      l_result NUMBER;
 BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'begin :n := ' || p || '; end;'
           USING OUT l_result;
      RETURN l_result;
 END;
```

Comment: I had a similar approach in the first version of my answer, but decided the SQL injection risk made it unwise. Ah, but I was selecting the result from dual; this is better in a way, but you could still have `p` doing something nasty.. You could pass in a string like `'1; execute immediate ''drop table x'''` for instance?

Comment: Sure, I thought you are interested in quick and dirty solution. In order to avoid SQL injection I would suggest first validating the expression (e.g. using regular expressions). The xml tricks suggested by Alex should also be safe